# Convert datetime from server to string javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

ASP.NET MVC 5 .Net 4.6.1 c#

I set a date on the server like so:

```
    public JsonResult GetDate()
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        return Json(date);
    }
```

When I call this method via ajax, the date is returned like so:

```
     Date(1464670800000)
```

I know I can format my date at the server, but i dont want to do that because the date format changes for different sections of the page, so i want to format the date client side. How do I convert that date object returned from the server to a formatted string (mm/dd/yy for instance) in javascript? Thanks

Comment: There's no built-in date-formatting functionality in JavaScript. If it's a simple format you can retrieve the date parts from the date object and convert them to strings and piece them together. For more complicated formatting, use a library like moment.js that has built-in format strings closer to those you know from C#.

Comment: @cory - I'm hoping someone knows of an awesome date library that was built in javascript. I'll look at moment. Thanks

Comment: Send a valid ISO string to page

Comment: Be aware of time zones.

Comment: Luckily, for this app, i will only have 1 time zone. Thanks for the warning anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it manually:

```js
    function formatDate(timestamp){
        var x=new Date(timestamp);
        var dd = x.getDate();
        var mm = x.getMonth()+1;
        var yy = x.getFullYear();
        return dd +"/" + mm+"/" + yy;
     }
    console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
```

Or you can use moments.js lib.

http://momentjs.com/

```
moment(date).format("DD/mm/YY");
```

Comment: Actually a small typo with moment js: it should be `DD/MM/YY` since 'mm' stands for minutes, as can be seen here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: Side-note, using moment isn't recommended anymore. Read the docs for better info (https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use a regex on these to only get the numbers

```
replace(/\D/g, ''))
```

And just pass your `Date(1464670800000)` through that and then into the `new Date` constructor and work with it from there.

```js
console.log(
  new Date(+"Date(1464670800000)".replace(/\D/g, ''))
)
//or for example, use LocaleDate
console.log(
  new Date(+"Date(1464670800000)".replace(/\D/g, '')).toLocaleDateString()
)
```

(*The `+` is converting the string to an int so that `"1464670800000"` just becomes `1464670800000` to conform to the `Date` constructor)*

Comment: This method works with the hardcoded "Date(14617120000)" but when i do this: timestamp = "Date(1464670800000)"; var d1 = new Date(timestamp.replace(/\D/g, '')); i get "invalid date". Your solution is what i'm looking for, i just need to see how to pass the value returned from the server without hardcoding.

Comment: @BoundForGlory - Don't forget the `+`! :) That is what makes the string into an int so the Date constructor can be used. `var d1 = new Date(+timestamp.replace(/\D/g, ''));`, see the **+**?

Comment: I got it...I left off the "+" symbol..This is EXACTLY what i was looking for. Thank you!